# How to convert list of elements into dictionary of dictionaries

Tags: python, json, list, dictionary, type-conversion

How to turn this list -

```
list = ['your name', 'mother', 'age', '43']
```

into this dictionary of dictionaries -

```
dict = {'your name': 
        {'mother': 
            {'age': '43'}
        }
    }
```

Comment: @quamrana          Well that's the only thing I want now.  I want to convert the list into that dictionary. But how?   Thanks for the comment by the way.

Comment: Will the list always contain 4 elements only?

Comment: @RahulHindocha yes

Comment: @Kirito Why do not you manually do this if all the lists are in the same pattern?                   
 `{lst[0] : {lst[1] : {lst[2] : lst[3]}}}`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One option is to iterate backwards over the list, and continuously update the result dict `D`:

```py
L = ['your name', 'mother', 'age', '43']

D = L[-1]  # '43'

for k in L[-2::-1]:
    D = {k: D}  # {'age': D}... {'mother': D}...

print(D)
```

Out:

```py
{'your name': {'mother': {'age': '43'}}}
```

Comment: No need to create the dict before iteration, just set `D=L[-1]`, the iteration does the rest. (`for k in L[-2::-1]: ...`).

Comment: @Rabinzel good point, didn't see that. updated :-)

Comment: Thanks to you all

Answer (score 0):

You can just hardcode the logic and then run this in a loop.

```
l = ['your name', 'mother', 'age', '43']
d = {}
d[l[0]] = {
    l[1]: {
        l[2]: l[3]
        }
    }
```